# Module 'shared_preferences_ios' not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I know this question has been posted tons of times and after going through all of them, i am still yet to fix the problem.

Running on Apple silicon mac, latest flutter, xcode, android studio and cocoapods.
Xcode open in workspace.

When i am trying to run with shared_preferences added I get module not found in XCode
[image]

In terminal i am getting this:

[image]

I have tried deleting pod file, flutter clean, build clean, changing IOS target version on pod file to match build and many other suggestions.

I am looking for any other suggestion that could help solve this problem.
The same module missing also came up with firebase, but i just removed it and forgot about it.

Comment: Please try this "flutter pub cache repair " and check it.

Comment: same problem persists

Comment: Which flutter version do you use?

Comment: It's telling me latest  3.0.5

Comment: Ok
First backup your ios folder in paste it into a safe place. delete the ios folder from the project.
Fired command "flutter create ."

Comment: Did that, same problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246856/discussion-between-rajesh-and-s3v3ns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete your podfile
Then

```
flutter pub get
```

Then

```
arch -x86_64 pod install
```

Then run again

Comment: This actually worked, why doesn't regular pod install solve this and you have to specify a platform?

Comment: Your iPhone doesn't run on the M1 silicone so you have to specify the architecture in the podfile so it builds correctly.

Comment: Gotcha, makes sense. Interesting that it didn't come out anywhere and adding shared preferences brought this problem out. Until now it has been working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Cocopods issue for M1 CocoaPods/CocoaPods#9890

First run

```
  sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi
```

Then run

```
  arch -x86_64 pod install
```